# What is the angular divergence of sun-rays?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, sun, geometric-optics

I just want to find a number and I could not. Does anyone has it or can calculate it easily? Just in geometric optics, without diffraction, atmospheric effects and etc.

Update: I think for me will be good enough to assume that the Sun is a disk, not sphere. and I need to know divergence in the space (no atmosphere) in the perpendicular plane like in this picture.

[image]

Update2: @hsinghal

Is it something like this?
[image]

Comment: Hint: work out the angle subtended by the Sun at your position, and sketch how this relates to the spread of angles of rays that reach you from the Sun.

Comment: Do you mean Sun angular size on the earth (32 minutes of arc) equals to divergence? or the same about solid angle?

Comment: There are two things. 1) Rays can reach a given point on Earth from any visible point on the Sun. So the rays arriving at the point form a converging cone. Find the angle from the distance to the Sun and its diameter. 2) Rays that leave a given point on the Sun can hit any point on the daytime side of Earth. If you are interested in the divergence of rays that hit two points, calculate it from the distance to the Sun and the distamce between the points.

Comment: It is too complicated. I made an update with clarification and picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

although the hint by @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance is sufficient to solve this problem but I would like to elaborate his hint.

you know diameter of the sun, and distance from earth to sun. Now take a point, the rays emerging from two extremes of the sun and passing from this point will have maximum angle between them and that will set an upper limit on the divergence.

$\theta=D/d$ where D is the diameter of sun and d is distance from earth to sun.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I updated my question with update2 and uploaded picture. Did you mean that?

Comment: @Zlelik you have correctly figured it out. At small angle $\tan (\theta) $~$  \theta$

Comment: Thanks. Yes, small angle tan⁡(θ)~θ and sin(θ)~θ. I just wanted to clarify.

Comment: If someone needs a number, I got number 0.53 Degrees for this θ or 0.009276 radians.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: I was thinking later. This angle should be the same for any point in the space. For example if I want to find this angle in the Jupiter where d is 5 times more than in the Earth I will get different angle.

Or this angle should be the same only for point source? and for big light source like Sun, it is not correct?

Comment: I think at Jupiter this angle will be smaller